# Popup window does not appear due to problems with CSS

Tags: html, css, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to reproduce the popup in [this page](https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/vhqym). However, when I add this code to my page nothing shows up. If I start looking at the CSS file within Adobe Dreamweaver, there are many errors in the CSS file. I suspect that's the reason the popup is not showing when I load the page. Attached is an image with some of the issues. In line 860 it's expecting an RBRACE. At line 869 the error is "unexpected token &". At line 873 it's unexpected token }. The same errors appear later on. When I analysed the code in codepen.io there were no issues, so I don't understand where the problem is.

This is the code I have so far:

In the html file:

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Info box</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            <p>This is done totally without JavaScript. Just HTML and CSS.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then later in the same html file:

```
  <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.overlay').show();       
        $('.popup').show();
    });
</script>
```

In the CSS file:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: opacity 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    &.light {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  .cancel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: default;
  }
  &:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.popup {
    margin: 75px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
  .light & {
    border-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #666;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  .content {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    &:last-child {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the visibility:hidden to display:none and also why don't you just hide everything in the .overlay class and use the show() method to display the content in the javascript

Comment: Initially the codepen.io code was supposed to have no javascript. Since I couldn't make it work I've been trying to add some js but to no avail. Your suggestion didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, The codepen is using [`SCSS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/) which is transformed to `CSS` and then it works. So, if you directly use that as CSS, it won't work and give errors. You need some pre-processor to process the SCSS to CSS and then use it.

e.g.
This is SCSS syntax (in codepen)

```
overlay {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  &:target {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

which gets converted to the following CSS (and is actually getting used)

```
overlay {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
overlay:target {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

So, you cannot use the former directly in your html without processing.

**Secondly**, the way codepen is working is by using a href's internal linking attribute. You create an internal link by href and then when the user clicks on the link, `target` attribute is added to the overlay class overriding the previously written CSS.

Have tried to partially fix it for you:

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Have fixed the CSS till here and so basic example is working fine now */

.popup {
  margin: 75px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  .light & {
    border-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #666;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  .content {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    &:last-child {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#popup1">Click Me</a>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Info box</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>This is done totally without JavaScript. Just HTML and CSS.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also achieve the same using javascript but that need code other than what you have written.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts!